# Enterprise library logging + dynamic connection string

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library

I am using the **enterprise library logging and exception handling**.

Currently I am adding the connection string in the configuration file, and this means that it is static.

My problem is that the user may connect to a different database each time depending on his user name. Is there any way to change the connection string at run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a CustomTraceListener

Answer (score -3):

You can set the Connection string at run time by using ConfiguratiomManager class from System.Configuration namaspace as below;

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString = "Your new Connection string";
```